# Checking for maximum value in the same column repeatedly and replacing with new found maximum

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to find the maximum value in a column and keep the same value until the next max value is found, if found then replace it with the new one, **in SQL as data lies in MS SQL Server**

Algorithm would be basically keep a global variable for MaxDelay and keep rewriting that with new max or run two 'for loops' one for current row and other for row-1 until next project is found.

Should I be using a mix of recursive query and funtion in SQL?
I tried Lag() but I'm unable to use Max() of Lag() due to windowed functions limitation.

```
SELECT *,
(select max(v) from (VALUES([Delay],Lag([Delay], 1) OVER(ORDER BY [Milestones], [Project Name])))as value(v)) as [MaxDate]
FROM dbo.[Scenario Testing with Previous Row]
```

*error:*

> Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Would appreciate if someone could give me some pointers.

```
Project Name    Milestones  Baseline Date   Actual Date Delay   Max Delay     Worst Case Date
Project 1   MS_1    12/12/2016  15/12/2016  3   3   15/12/2016
Project 1   MS_2    14/12/2016  16/12/2016  2   3   17/12/2016
Project 1   MS_3    31/12/2016  09/01/2017  9   9   09/01/2017
Project 1   MS_4    11/01/2017  12/01/2017  1   9   20/01/2017
Project 1   MS_5    21/01/2017  24/01/2017  3   9   30/01/2017
Project 1   MS_6    01/02/2017  15/02/2017  14  14  15/02/2017
Project 1   MS_7    15/02/2017  16/02/2017  1   14  01/03/2017
Project 1   MS_8    26/02/2017  26/02/2017  0   14  12/03/2017
Project 1   MS_9    31/03/2017  31/03/2017  0   14  14/04/2017
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results *in the question* as text tables.  If you put 4 spaces at the beginning of each row, then the data will align.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a cumulative max, then use the appropriate function.  Something like this:

```
select t.*,
       max(delay) over (order by [Milestones], [Project Name]) as running_max
from dbo.[Scenario Testing with Previous Row] t;
```

Comment: Wow!That was helpful. Thanks.